# How to solve Deeplearning4j and Tensorflow error?

Tags: deeplearning4j

I am getting the error:
Failed to define class org.tensorflow.framework.DataType
I looked through the latest jars for Deeplearning4j and can not find it. Do I need to download from Maven the Tensorflow jars? I am running the new Deeplearning4j framework inside a j2ee Wildfly server for a web service using java 1.8.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out where it is located. I downloaded the nd4j-tensor-1.0.0-beta4 jar and error went away.
-Tony

Answer (score 0):

Deeplearning4j maintainer here. Cobbling together dependencies is always a bad idea:

Few things:

1. beta4 is decently old at this point and I would not recommend using it.
2. I'm guessing you're likely mixing versions. If you are, please don't. Always use the same version. The whole dl4j stack will always have the same versions and if different versions work together it's because you're lucky. It's not deliberate.
3. Generally try to use maven/gradle where possible for resolving dependencies. There's lots of small jars that can be mixed/matched.